# I can't connect Elasticache to Elastic Beanstalk (In VPC)

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I have a VPC with 2 public subnets in different availability zones (public subnet-2a and public-subnet-2b). I have two private subnets (private-2a-EB-Instance, private-2b-EB-Instance), and two other private subnets for Elasticache (private-2a-EB-Instance, private-2b-EB-Instance), these two subnets for elasticache are part of a subnet group that I use when creating my Elasticache clusters.

I have create a security group for my ElastiCache(redis) and I have changed its inbound rules so it can accept connection from the security group of my ElasticBeanstalk environment. Didn't solve the problem.

I have followed the instructions on AWS' website, and I can't get it to work. I wonder what I am doing wrong. I am using [socket-io-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-redis) and I am wondering if that may be part of the problem.

I have used the .config file offered [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-environment-resources-elasticache.html) , but I get an error when deploying the app. It says there was an error creating it.

I created the cluster from the console and tried to connect it to my EB app using the "Primary Endpoint", but I get the error:

```
Error: Redis connection to https://myelasticache.xxxxxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com:6379 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://myelasticache.xxxxxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: When you login to the EB instance, and manually from there try accessing the EC, it also times out, or its only from your application?

Comment: I have not tried to connect manually to my EC2 instances. Is that what I should do?

Comment: That's what I would do. Have to establish if the connectivity issue is widespread (i.e. any instance in your vpc can't connect to it), or is it local (only your app).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have included `https://` in what is supposed to be the hostname. Redis does not connect over HTTP, it uses its own protocol. The error message `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://myelasticache.xxxxxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com` indicates that it is trying to resolve `https://myelasticache.xxxxxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com` when you want it to use `myelasticache.xxxxxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com`.

So try removing `https://` and see if it works or if you get another error.

Comment: I removed it, thanks for catching that. I was able to deploy the app its health is OK, which is really werid. When I check the logs I see this though: "Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379". It is trying to connect to localhost, is that normal? It doesn't seem to be normal to me.

Comment: I think most redis libraries default to localhost. As you indicate, that isn't going to work when you want to connect to elasticache. Somehow the hostname isn't being set at all now. Most redis libraries should try to use the environment variable REDIS_URL if it is present, so you could try that, with the value being `redis://myelasticache.xxxxxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com:6379`.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, but I am not entirely sure why my solution worked. After I made the change to the url, I put the port and the endpoint in the EB environment variables and all of a sudden it started working. It is so weird. Thanks!